# "KeyError 0.0" when using another dataframe containing standard deviation as error bars for the y axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code that I am unable to figure out the solution to (despite much googling and searching).
Basically, I have a scipt that compiles two files derived from the same data - one file is a table of the average at each wavelength for six groups, and the other is the exact same but containing the standard deviation (both tables are the same size, same headers, etc). Plotting the files (df2) for the average produces graphs, no problem.

However when I try to use the dataframe containing the standard deviation (df3) values, as the error bars for the graph, I get "KeyError 0.0".
Is anyone able to help me figure out what's going wrong? Much appreciated and many thanks.

My script is below.

```
wave = pd.read_csv("Wavelength_to_Index_Conversion.csv") #contains a list of wavelengths used to use later on
##
#GET AVERAGE VALUES OF DATA FROM EACH FILE
##
for filename in os.listdir(indir):
    print (i)
    df1 = pd.read_csv(indir + filename) #imports file
    print(filename)
    filename = filename[:-12] #removes extra filename and extension
    print(filename)
    if i == 0:
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=None,index=df1.index)
    e = df1['Average']
    df2 = df2.assign(temp=e.values)
    print (filename)
    df2.rename(columns={'temp': str(filename)}, inplace=True)

    i = i+1

df2.set_index(wave['Wavelength'], inplace=True)
df2.to_csv("Total_Average.csv")
df2t = df2.T
df2t.to_csv("Total_Average_T.csv")

##
## GET STD DEV
##
i = 0
for filename in os.listdir(indir):
    print (i)
    df1 = pd.read_csv(indir + filename) #imports file
    print(filename)
    filename = filename[:-12]
    print(filename)
    if i == 0:
        df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=None,index=df1.index)
    e = df1['Std Dev']
    df3 = df3.assign(temp=e.values)
    print (filename)
    df3.rename(columns={'temp': str(filename)}, inplace=True)

    i = i+1
df3.set_index(wave['Wavelength'], inplace=True)
df3.to_csv("Total_Std Dev.csv")

#plt.rc('font', family='serif', size=13)
#plt.rc('font', family='san-serif', size=13)


#plt.ylim(0, 60)    
#plt.xlim(400, 900)
plt.title('Title',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Reflectance (%)',fontsize=15)
    #plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis=u'both', tight=False)
plt.grid(False)
df2.plot(x = wave['Wavelength'], xlim=(400,850), ylim=(0,60), yerr=df3) #ERROR HERE WHENEVER yerr=df3 IS USED
```

EDIT:

Here's the error I'm given.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-d121c6b80d76>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/user/Documents/PhD/Data Manipulation and Graphs/Spectrometry/Plotting All Files into a Graph [X]/Plotting Spectral.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/Documents/PhD/Data Manipulation and Graphs/Spectrometry/Plotting All Files into a Graph [X]')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/jdstam/Documents/PhD/Data Manipulation and Graphs/Spectrometry/Plotting All Files into a Graph [X]/Plotting Spectral.py", line 115, in <module>
    df2.plot(x = wave['Wavelength'], xlim=(400,850), ylim=(0,60), yerr=df3)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 3671, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 2556, in plot_frame
    **kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 2384, in _plot
    plot_obj.generate()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 987, in generate
    self._make_plot()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1664, in _make_plot
    **kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1678, in _plot
    lines = MPLPlot._plot(ax, x, y_values, style=style, **kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\plotting.py", line 1293, in _plot
    return ax.errorbar(x, y, **kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1811, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2963, in errorbar
    iterable(yerr[0]) and len(yerr[0]) > 1))):

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 557, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 3884, in get_value
    loc = self.get_loc(k)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 3942, in get_loc
    tolerance=tolerance)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1759, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3979)

  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 157, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3843)

  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 498, in pandas.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:9556)

  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 504, in pandas.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:9494)

KeyError: 0.0
```

EDI2:

i. Output for df2.head()

```
            Mon18th_C24_20%  Mon18th_C24_50%  Mon18th_C24_80%  Mon18th_Col0_20%  Mon18th_Col0_50%  Mon18th_Col0_80%
Wavelength                                                                                                         
341.514           -1.963704        32.036429        13.413667         -1.396250            39.647        -23.480313
341.892           -1.963704        32.036429        13.413667         -1.396250            39.647        -23.480313
342.269           11.653704       -44.896786       180.915667         -6.503438            38.840         50.237812
342.646           18.801111       305.569286       532.147000        -27.857500           504.351         66.496562
343.024           28.421852        48.280000        65.551000        968.713437            79.782         63.419688
```

ii. Output for df3.head()

```
            Mon18th_C24_20%  Mon18th_C24_50%  Mon18th_C24_80%  Mon18th_Col0_20%  Mon18th_Col0_50%  Mon18th_Col0_80%
Wavelength                                                                                                         
341.514          103.027866       121.768024        98.039234         60.476486        101.865202        325.329848
341.892          103.027866       121.768024        98.039234         60.476486        101.865202        325.329848
342.269           59.441182       719.315230       643.463142         52.176211        606.273169        177.225557
342.646           41.717983       820.680259       922.506270         73.360823        689.563817         93.132120
343.024           47.129664        75.400200        73.011963       1728.405146         71.020783         52.873068
```

Comment: Can you show full error stack?

Comment: Will add to main post

Comment: Just a guess: it looks like `df2` has column called `0.0` which `df3` doesn't have.

Comment: So I don't know if this will help, but they all only have column names of "Wavelength, Mon18th_C24_20%, Mon18th_C24_50%, Mon18th_C24_80%, Mon18th_Col0_20%, Mon18th_Col0_50%, Mon18th_Col0_80%". Both dataframes also say they have 6 columns (the index is called wavelength), and 2048 rows. Thanks for helping so far.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include `df2.head()` and `df3.head()`?

Comment: Added to main post.

Comment: Ok it's weird. It seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11858). Check if the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137961/pandas-plotting-with-yerr-gives-key-error-0) solves your problem.

Comment: So, by renaming the wavelength index as "0" and having the first index value also be "0" at least I am able to plot the graph now (no error bars are visible though unfortunately, but at least that's progress I guess? hahaha). How do I give you rep/whatever for helping me btw?

Comment: Ha ha, I guess it's progress yes. No worries for the rep, help is more important :)